# Excel Find Number Within a Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

I have table in Excel with range of numbers, and next to it I wrote a group number that i want for this range.

I have the number 61 that i want to get his group number, which is 3.

What is the formula i need to use?

here is the whole thing:

[image: my excel sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B:D,3,TRUE)
```

Comment: it works! I use a lot of VLOOKUP but never using TRUE in the fourth argument. Wanted to ask also how did you put the image like that in the original post? :)

Comment: @AG9 you need to have a certain amount of rep to load photos.